# P146 example from the book "R in action"

Tags: r

From book "R in action" page 146 it has an example of group descriptive statistics by

```
vars <- c("mpg", "hp", "wt")
...
> dstats <- function(x)(c(mean=mean(x), sd=sd(x)))
> by(mtcars[vars], mtcars$am, dstats)
```

but when I input this into R what I get is

```
> Error in is.data.frame(x) : 
>(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
>In addition: Warning message:
>In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

I do not know what happens here. Can anyone gives me a help. Thanks.

Comment: you can almost match what the book has with `by(mtcars[vars], mtcars$am, Vectorize(dstats))` keeping everything else the same

Comment: cool that indeed works. Thx

Comment: but when I transform the `mtcar[vars]` to data frame by using `as.data.frame(mtcars[vars])` the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do `?by()` in your R Console.

In the help, you'll find the following mentioned for the `FUN`

```
by(data, INDICES, FUN, ..., simplify = TRUE)

FUN a function to be applied to (usually data-frame) subsets of data.
```

**Update**

This probably more has to do with the way mean() and sd() are defined. They both on support vector, not data frames.

Checkout the examples below, and see the difference that comes with `mean()` with and without `Vectorize()`:

```
x <- data.frame( a = c(1, 2, 4), b = c(1, 2, 4))
```

Now, if you do:

```
by(x, 1:3, mean)
```

You will get the following error:

```
Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(data[x, , drop = FALSE], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(data[x, , drop = FALSE], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
3: In mean.default(data[x, , drop = FALSE], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

But upon adding `Vectorize()`:

```
by(x, 1:3, Vectorize(mean))
1:3: 1
a b 
1 1 
------------------------------------------------------- 
1:3: 2
a b 
2 2 
------------------------------------------------------- 
1:3: 3
a b 
4 4
```

Also from the forums:

> by(as.data.frame(mtcars[vars]), mtcars$am, dstats)
>
> The problem is with the by function. If you replace dstats with mean
>   or sd, it still does not work. It only works with the summary
>   function. I wonder how the author got the output in the book?

Source: https://forums.manning.com/posts/list/32059.page

Comment: Yes, it is true. But if I use `Vectorize(mean)` or `Vectorize(dstats)`, it indeed gives right result. I am still confused why it works after reading help

Comment: @user6227636 This probably more has to do with the way mean() and sd() are defined. They both on support vector(), not data frames. I have updated my answer with some explanation, hope it helps.

Comment: Yes. If they do not take data frames but vectors as variables, then things can be explained. Thanks a lot.